# Firefox Dictionary addon

Tags: firefox, dictionary, firefox-addon

Can anyone suggest me an addon which shows definition of the word when i select it in on the page using mouse cursor.
To be more specific when i select or highlight some text the addon should automatically search for that word on the internet and show me results near the selected text like a pop-up note.
I knew that there is an addon like this because i have used it in the past but i forgot the name of the addon.

Below is the image of the process i am explaining of, i.e. when i select or highlight something in the paragraph the addon should give me definition of that word in return pop-up note or anything like that.
[image: Here is a snapshot of what i exactly want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching a lot on the net i came up with the solution.

FastestFox 5.1.9

> FastestFox helps you browse faster by speeding up common tasks such as
>   searching Wikipedia, searching Google, visiting your bookmarks, and
>   more. FastestFox was written by Yongqian Li. It was formerly called
>   "SmarterFox" and "Smarter Wikipedia".